# Loop instruction does not stop

Tags: assembly, x86-16

so I need to read 10 numbers from the keyboard and I've been trying to do that, but the loop does not stop. If I type 1 ten times and hit enter after each time, the program stops but for other combinations it won't work. I'm a beginner in assembly so every explanation is welcome. Thank you.

```
.model small
.stack 200h
.data
max db 0
min db 0 
numar db 0


.code
programStart:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
xor ax,ax
xor cx,cx
xor bx,bx

mov dl, 10

mov cx, 10
start:

readNumber:

mov ah, 01h
int 21h 

cmp al, 13
je stack

mov bl, al
sub bl, 30h

mov al, numar
mul dl
add al, bl
mov numar, al

jmp readNumber

stack:
xor ax,ax
mov al,numar
push ax
mov numar,0
loop start

end programStart
```

Comment: You don't exit your program after `loop start`. You have to have your program exit back to DOS.Put `mov ax, 4C00h` `int 21h`  after `loop start`

Comment: Are you sure that int 21h doesn’t change cx and dx?  I usually assume all function calls (and system calls) change ax, cx, and dx, unless I check. And it’s hard to check for DOS interrupts, since there’s no spec.

Comment: @prl back in the day most `int 21h` that didn't need to return values (or just one value) generally didn't clobber registers other than AL/AH/AX. There are some exceptions. Looking at ctyme` suggests Int 21h/AH=1h only modifies AL. http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm